# Add ACF field in a query

Tags: wp-query, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to set category_name of a query using an ACF text field but I am getting all posts instead the post of the category I want.

```
          $category1 = the_field('category1');
          $args1=array(
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'post_type'      => 'post',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'category_name' => $category1,
            );
```

Does anybody have any solution on that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_field` is used to output, `get_field` is used to return.
So instead of

```php
$category1 = the_field('category1');
```

It should be

```php
$category1 = get_field('category1');
```

Comment: you are absolutely right! I totally missed that. Thanks